# how to update the uitablview of detailview on row select of master view or load new view in detailview?

Tags: ios, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

am using xcode and developing one master detailview app for ipad

my requirement is there is two tablview ..one for masterviewcontroller and 2nd for detailview controller

and on select row of masterview i want to change the tableview data of detailview or another way is to reload new view controller in detailview..

so can anyone please tell me..how can i do that?
or can anyone provides me tutorial for that ?

i have tried to goggle the things but didn't succeeded.

i have tried to push new view controller on click of masterdetailview tableview cell with following but its navigating the masterdetailview to my new viewcontroller..but what i want is to navigate from detailview controller to new view controller after click on master detailview table row

```
StatusesTableViewController *statusviewController = [[StatusesTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:"StatusesTableViewController" bundle:nil];



    [self.navigationController pushViewController:statusviewController animated:YES];
    [statusviewController release];
```

Comment: When You Click on MasterView's Table Cell then you go to the next view right ? and on next view there is another uitableView everytime you do this nextView's table will reload automatically.

Comment: Have you looked at the standard master detail view template created for you by Xcode?

Comment: yes...like that...and i dont want to hide the master detailview after clikc on uitableview cell of master detailview

Comment: @win.i have created a sample app.but i just blank after creating only one tableview..now i dont know wht to do next to load new tableview in detailview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `MasterViewController.m`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
    detailViewController.arrData = //YOUR ARRAY
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

in DetailViewController.m

in `(void)viewDidLoad`

```
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
[tableView reloadData];
```

And implement required delegate and datasource method of the DetailViewController.m with your array.

Comment: ok i will implement that but if u can suggest me for another way that how can i load new viewcontroller in detailview on click of row of masterview controller